# A third degree surface and a touching sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

Let consider a surface $z=1/(xy)$ and a sphere defined by $(x-1.5)^2+(y-1.5)^2+(z-1.5)^2=3/4$. The sphere touches the surface at (1,1,1). Is it possible to prove that point (1,1,1) is the only intersection based on the fact that this surface is convex  and sphere's radius is not large as given?

Comment: Decent question, wrong forum.

Comment: Consider the polynomial of degree three with roots $x,y,z$. The information given implies that it is equal to $f(t)=t^3-st^2 +(s^2/2 -3s/2 + 3)t -1$. Three roots are real iff the discriminant is nonnegative. This gives you a polynomial inequality on $s$, which you presumably can check.

Comment: I am getting discriminant to be $(1/4)(s-3)^2(-s^4 + 6s^3 - 24s^2 +56s - 60)$. The remaining polynomial of degree $4$ is negative for all $s$.

Comment: Somebody of the usual set "put on hold" may prove it? Will be thankful...

Comment: Certainly, computer gives accurate enough coordinates of four roots to know that they are complex. If that's not enough for you, try to write it as opposite of sum of squares of quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Lev Borisov - I proved the underlying inequality of 3rd degree as a lemma for some result in joint paper. But the proof is not nice or short. So I am interesting to find another one using geometry and convexity.

Comment: You can try to take log coords $x=e^a,y=e^b,z=e^c$ and then see if the inequality $(e^a-3/2)^2+(e^b-3/2)^2+(e^c-3/2)^2\leq 3/4$ gives a convex shape. But I think that my approach with the discriminant is short, if not "nice".

Comment: You can do Lagrange multiplers for $xyz$ on the sphere. This will give you three equations like $xy=(2z-3)\lambda$ and so on. By subtracting one of such equation from the other you get $x=z$ or $y=-2\lambda$. Either way you get linear relations on $x,y,z$ and it should be easy to solve. Then you will get $xyz\geq 1$ with minimum at $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Sergei Can you add a reference to the joint paper and/or motivation, please

Comment: @Lev Borisov - I solved it by Lagrange. The aim of the question is to find geometrical solution using convexity of related surface.

Comment: @Vladimir Zolotov - pochtaname(c)gmail.com

Comment: It is easy to see by convexity of sorts that there are no other solutions near $(1,1,1)$. Specifically, let $x=e^a$, $y=e^b$, $z=e^c$. Then you have to solve $e^{2a}-3e^{a} + .... = -6$ for $a+b+c=0$. By Jensen's you will not have nontrivial solutions in the region where $f(t)=e^{2t}-3e^t$ is convex.

Comment: The most elegant solution is to write "This is an easy exercise which we leave to the reader."

Comment: The closest points to $(1,1,1)$ on $xyz=1$ are of the form $(a,1/\sqrt a,1/\sqrt a)$. So, it suffices to check this curve.

Comment: Which has curvature $< 1$, while the circle of radius $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ has curvature $> 1$. And we are done.

Comment: @LevBorisov -so "easy"? Still no solution based on convexity, sorry.

Comment: @VladimirZolotov - may you give more details, with proper references on connection of curvature with value of radius? I do not know much of diffgeometry...

Comment: @Lev Borisov - I missed your idea with discriminant. You checked it is negative, but it has to be nonnegative?

Comment: Correct. The discriminant is $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(x-z)^2$, so if the roots are real, then it is nonnegative.

Comment: My argument was wrong. It only works only for $a > (2/5)^{1/3}$, where the curvature is monotonic.